# Overload functions with paramters of `T` and `T | undefined` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I defined a simple function with overload siganatures:

```
function toUpper(value: string | undefined): string | undefined;
function toUpper(value: string): string ;
function toUpper(value: string | undefined): string | undefined {
    return value?.toString();
}
```

And hope when passing value is `string` that the return type is `string, and when passing value is` string | undefined`that the return type is`string | undefined`

But the simple call reports compilation error:

```
const x: string = toUpper('abc');
```

```
TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Please help how to define the function correctly, thanks!

Comment: FWIW: When writing functions that use specific methods on parameters, it's helpful to be exact with your definitions so that your function is more useful. e.g. In the case that you only use a `toString` or `toUpperCase` method on a nullable parameter, you can indicate that in the function signature [like this](https://tsplay.dev/N5QKPN) — `string` types aren't the only inputs that can have such methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Function overload signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) need to be sorted from most specific to least specific. Here we're working with [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) hence the signature with fewer union members (`string`) must be written before the other one (`string | undefined`).

> ❔ Why: TypeScript chooses the first matching overload when resolving function calls. When an earlier overload is “more general” than a later one, the later one is effectively hidden and cannot be called.

See [function overloads Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#function-overloads)

So your overload signature that takes a `string` was actually being ignored and `string | undefined` was returned instead which is not assignable to the [explicit type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) of `const x: string = ...`. -> compiler error.

```
function toUpper(value: string): string;
function toUpper(value: string | undefined): string | undefined {
    return value?.toString();
}

const x: string = toUpper('abc');
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOBVADugpgJwBQBuAhgDYhYBciAzlDjGAOYCUVt9TA3AFCiSwJkaTLkKlybOg0aIAPonAATLMAZZFrGlKZyFYZarDrEAb26ILiHFiggcSYmSwB%20AHQoAytsZ5mPAL7c3BAItIgAHpIcMgC8QhjY%20ADkRABGEEl%20QA)

Comment: Rather than "most specific to least specific", I think it's helpful to think about a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement as an analog: the _first_ signature (evaluated in order of top-to-bottom) to which the type information can be assigned will be the one which is matched.

Comment: That's a neat way to think about it. "Do sort overloads by putting the more general signatures after more specific signatures"... is straight out of the [TypeScript Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#function-overloads).

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have stated, the ordering of your function overloads is important, however I would also like to point out that you are lacking a correct overload to handle `undefined` values. With the following overload signatures your input could be either a string or `undefined` and the output will be of the corresponding type:

```js
function toUpper(value: string): string ;
function toUpper(value: undefined): undefined;
function toUpper(value: string | undefined): string | undefined {
    return value?.toString();
}

const x = toUpper('abc'); // x is string
const y = toUpper(undefined); // y is undefined
```

For the sake of completeness, you could also tackle typing this function using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html):

```js
function toUpper<T extends string | undefined>(value: T): T {
    return value?.toString() as T;
}

const input: string | undefined = 'test';
const x: string = toUpper(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try changing the order of the functions like below

```
function toUpper(value: string): string ;
function toUpper(value: string | undefined): string | undefined;
function toUpper(value: string | undefined): string | undefined {
    return value?.toString();
}

const x: string = toUpper('abc');
```

it should work